# Retrieving precise drop position of Android View

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

The target application allows the user to drag/drop views to move them in a FrameLayout or store them in another LinearLayout.

The overall mechanism works but I can't get the precision I need on the position when the view is dropped, it "jumps" a little further. How could I retrieve the position of the drag shadow to put the dropped view exactly where the shadow was, in order to avoid any "jump" artefact?

For the sake of the example, the layout is pretty simple, here's an overview with two TextView objects that can be moved around (I removed all the details):

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/repository"/>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frame">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/view1"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/view2"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

First, to improve the start position of the drag shadow itself, I'm overriding `onProvideShadowMetrics`. Thanks to that, the view doesn't jump when the user starts dragging it:

```java
private class MyDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {
    private float x, y;

    public MyDragShadowBuilder(View view, float x, float y) {
        super(view);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point size, Point touchPoint) {
        super.onProvideShadowMetrics(size, touchPoint);
        touchPoint.set((int) x, (int) y);
    }
}
```

Then an implementation of the `OnTouchListener` is used to start the drag operation:

```java
private class LongClickListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            if (tv != null) {
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                MyDragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new MyDragShadowBuilder(v, event.getX(), event.getY());
                v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
                v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The drop operation is where I would like to retrieve the initial x, y position of the "finger" in the view, to position the view exactly as the shadow.

```java
private class DragListener implements View.OnDragListener {
    private final Class<?> FRAMELAYOUT_CLASS = FrameLayout.class;
    private final Class<?> LINEARLAYOUT_CLASS = LinearLayout.class;
    private Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
    private Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                v.setBackground(enterShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                v.setBackground(normalShape);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
                ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) v;
                if (container.getClass() == FRAMELAYOUT_CLASS) {
                    // If I could just get shadowBuilder here, I would be
                    // able to retrieve its initial (x,y) offset
                    // or its final (x,y) position, both work...
                    view.setX(event.getX());
                    view.setY(event.getY());
                } else if (container.getClass() == LINEARLAYOUT_CLASS) {
                    // In a LinearLayout we remove any offset:
                    view.setX(0);
                    view.setY(0);
                } else
                    return false;
                owner.removeView(view);
                container.addView(view);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                v.setBackground(normalShape);
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

All that is set in the `OnCreate` method of the activity:

```java
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    View v = findViewById(R.id.view1);
    v.setOnTouchListener(new LongClickListener());
    v = findViewById(R.id.view2);
    v.setOnTouchListener(new LongClickListener());
    v = findViewById(R.id.frame);
    v.setOnDragListener(new DragListener());
    v = findViewById(R.id.repository);
    v.setOnDragListener(new DragListener());
}
```

Thanks in advance for any tip on how I should get this information!

---

**EDIT**: Obviously I could pass the data in the ClipData but that would be awkward (especially if I need to pass larger data sets in the future, serialization is an overkill here):

```
ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText(
    "pos", 
    String.format("%d %d", (int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()));
v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
```

...

```
if (container.getClass() == FRAMELAYOUT_CLASS) {
    ClipData data = event.getClipData();
    String[] pos = ((String)data.getItemAt(0).getText()).split(" ");
    int x = Integer.valueOf(pos[0]);
    int y = Integer.valueOf(pos[1]);
    view.setX(event.getX() - x);
    view.setY(event.getY() - y);
```